# AS3 - Checking for active LAN wifi

Tags: actionscript-3, wifi, lan

In Actionscript you can easilly check for an active Internet connection using the URLMonitor Class like so

```
public function checkNetwork():void {
            if (_monitor != null) {
                if (_monitor.hasEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS)) {
                    _monitor.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, checkHTTP);
                }
                _monitor=null;
            }
            _monitor=new URLMonitor(new URLRequest('http://www.google.com'));
            _monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, checkHTTP);
            _monitor.start();

        }
```

Is there a way to simply check for an active wifi LAN instead? (no internet)

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by active Wi-Fi? Available, or connected? Either ways I don't think this is possible with Flash (it is possible with AIR). URLMonitor simply pings specific url by given interval, it's not a magic :)

Comment: actually I think it is possible using NetworkInfo, though don't have it working 100% yet. check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
private function init():void{ NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.NETWORK_CHANGE, onNetwork_ChangeHandler);
    }

        public function checkNetwork():void {

            if (flash.net.NetworkInfo.isSupported) {
                vNetworkInterfaces=getDefinitionByName('flash.net.NetworkInfo')['networkInfo']['findInterfaces']();
                trace("log","flash.net.NetworkInfo.isSupported");
                var hasWifi:Boolean=false;
                for each (var networkInterface:Object in vNetworkInterfaces) {
                    if (networkInterface.active && (networkInterface.name == "en0" || networkInterface.name == "en1"))
                        hasWifi=true;


                }
                trace("has Wifi : " + hasWifi);


                _isNetwork=hasWifi;


                if (_isNetwork == false) {


                    trace('No wifi connection. Please seek assistance!');
                }

            }
        }




        private function onNetwork_ChangeHandler(e:Event):void {
            checkNetwork();
        }
```

Comment: I've used something similar in AIR, but I had problems with what `active` actually means. That's why I asked you if you want to know if you are connected to the wi-fi? I hope it works, I'll be happy to see the result! :)